# Convert an RDD with list of unicode data to an RDD of tuples in Spark with Python

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

I have an `RDD` with `list` of `unicode` data like:

```
[[u'2002-03-31',u'emp1',u'20000'],[u'2002-05-11',u'emp2',u'23050'],[u'2002-05-17',u'emp1',u'23300']...]
```

and I want to convert it to `RDD` with `tuple` like:

```
[(u'2002-03-31',u'emp1',u'20000'),(u'2002-05-11',u'emp2',u'23050'),(u'2002-05-17',u'emp1',u'23300')...]
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply map with `tuple`:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    [u'2002-03-31', u'emp1', u'20000'],
    [u'2002-05-11', u'emp2', u'23050'],
    [u'2002-05-17', u'emp1', u'23300']])

tuples = rdd.map(tuple)
tuples.first()
## ('2002-03-31', 'emp1', '20000')
```