# How to convert a dataframe or RDD to a List of Tuples?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, tuples

I have a function

```
def f(tuples: Seq[Product]) : Unit = if (tuples.size>0) {
   // etc using tuples.foreach( x=>  { ...  x.productIterator.foreach(...) })
}
```

and need to call it passing a DataFrame, `f( myDF.rdd.? )`. **How to call the function by dataframe?**
(or how to cast? how to collectAsTuples?)

PS: need a "generic cast", perhaps something as `rdd.map(genericTuple)`, not a solution specialized tuple.

---

Note for down-voters: thre are supposed [python solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112510/287948), but no **Scala solution**.

Comment: Returning Unit, hmm that doesn't seem right

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís it is to simplify question (the real function generates a file to FileSystem and returns some flags).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question is clear enough, but this could help you:

You can always use a `case class` (https://docs.scala-lang.org/es/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html.html) on `Scala` to cast your `DF` to a `Dataset`, like: `df.as[YourCaseClass]`.

After that, and if you need mandatory get a `List`, you can use `.collectAsList()` over that `Dataset`.

The datatype of your items in that list will be the `case class` that you defined for the initial `cast`.

Comment: .collectAsList() is Java, in Scala it is only .collect(), and it will return an Array, then you can do a .toList

Comment: That's not completely true. `collectAsList` is Java, yes, but it still can be used by `Scala` and it does not return an `Array`, it returns a `java.util.List[YourCaseClass]`

Comment: Yes but using the Java list is the same as using Java, don't do that lol

Comment: "kind of"... anyways, I agree that the `scala` native alternative is the best one: `df.collect().toList`